# Unreasonable error calling function in C - Program to sort an array

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, mips

I wrote a program that receive from user a series of numbers (<=20) while the last '0' means end of series (not included in series storing).
2 arrays (x,y) size 20 (0-19 + 1 for the '0') must be zeros, and m means number of organs in Y array.

The user must enter numbers ascending (it is ok 4ex. 1,2,2,3,7,8,...,0) and end with a '0' of course, if not, appropriate error message will appear, and program will shut off.

We can be sure the user will keep the <=20 numbers of input.

Y array will be (if everything went ok with X array) a sorted array of X but without duplicates.
'm' will be number of organs in Y exclude '0' of course.

Function SIFT must only organize the Y array for being printed from main().

Example:

If user will store in X: 1,1,2,3,5,5,5,6

On screen will be: m = 5  Y = 1,2,3,5,6

**My tryout:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void SIFT(int x_arr[ ], int y_arr[]);

int main ()
{
    int x[20] = {0} , y[20] = {0};
    int m=0,temp=0,curr=0,i=0,j=0;

    printf("Please enter your numbers now:\n\n");

    /*enter numbers one by one. if x[i+1] value < x[i] value, err msg.
      when user want to end the series he must enter '0' which means end of string (it wont       included in x[]) */
    while ( ( temp = getchar() ) != '0' )
    {
        if (temp >= curr)
        {
            x[i] = temp;
            curr = temp;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("The numbers are not at the right order !\n\nProgram will now terminate...\n\n");
        }
    }

    SIFT(x,y);

    for (i=0 ; y[i]=='0' ; i++) /*strlen(y) without ('0')'s includes*/
        m++;

    /*Prints  m , y's organs*/
    printf("\n\nm = %d",m);
    printf("Y = ");
    while (y[j]!='0')
    {
        printf ("%d ,",y[j]);
        j++;
    }

void SIFT(int x_arr[ ], int y_arr[])
{
    int i=0,j=0;

    while (x_arr[i] != '0')
    {
        if (x_arr[i] == x_arr[i+1]) /*if current val. equals next val. -> jump dbl at x_arr*/
        {
            y_arr[j] = x_arr[i];
            i+=2;
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            y_arr[j]=x_arr[i];
            i++;
            j++;
        }
    }    

}

return 0;
}
```

**The error I'm getting from the gcc is:**

```
gcc -g -ansi -pedantic -Wall 2.c -o 2   
2.c: In function ‘main’:
2.c:43: warning: ISO C forbids nested functions
2.c:43: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
/tmp/ccyZNfkF.o: In function `main':
/home/student/Desktop/2/2.c:29: undefined reference to `SIFT'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [2] Error 1
```

**And another question:**

I would like to convert this code to the MIPS Assembly code, is there a short and fast way to do so ?

Thanks all you guys !!

Comment: Is this mayhaps an exercise project for a Computer Architecture course?  If so, maybe this should be tagged with `homework`.

Comment: I was looking for the "not a real question / too localized" reason. OP had a syntax error (missing curly brace); he fixed it; the compiler stopped telling him about the missing curly brace.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't close main function **before** declaration of SIFT, so SIFT is declared inside of main which is forbidden.

Fix it by returning from main before the definition of `SIFT()`:

```
...
return 0;
}

void SIFT(int x_arr[ ], int y_arr[])
{
    int i=0,j=0;
...
```

Comment: yes he did, main is closed. It looks like there's a SIFT function nested in it, which is the problem. if he does just those changes, there's a stray `return 0; }` at the end of the code and main does not return anything (okayish, but not good)

Comment: You wrote it inside the main function, look again.

Comment: :) can you help me understand why it always shows "The numbers are not at the right order..." msg ?

Comment: This is a different question, please ask it separately. If this is homework, please tag it as such, and people will be nicer. Also, if an answer was the needed answer, mark it by clicking the tick to its right.